# Help me catch someone red handed on our server.

Tags: linux

I first  tried to log in this morning and our password was changed on our ubuntu server.

I contacted our server support and they told me that I had just been fat fingering the password.

I thought it was fishy, I am not the type of person to mistype a password and blame the IT guy.

I looked at the history file and sure enough the password was changed but not by me.

I called our server support out and they said that they were just verifying the password. makes no sense.

Now there are 10 lines in the history file that has been deleted.

I smell something fishy, I now can't sftp in, but I still have an active session through SSH.

Is there a log file that can tell me who edited a file and when.

Is there any other log files that can help me catch this person and find out for sure what is going on.

This is our production server and it makes me nervous having someone running a without us asking. As of right now I can't prove anything strange is going on, but I know there is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look in the various log files in /var/log/secure there should be password changes, failed logins, etc.

Comment: It's a shared account/password, correct? How would you hope to limit your scope to a certain individual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a log file that can tell me who edited a file and when.

```
find / -mmin -90 -printf '%p\t%a\n'
```

This will list all files changed in the last 90 minutes and when they were changed. It does not say who changed it though ([this is not possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/97831/who-last-modified-file)).

And as Hae0 said looking at the bash history (and the logs in /var/log) is always a good idea. The root history should be here:

```
/root/.bash_history
```

And the histories for the other users here:

```
/home/<username>/.bash_history
```

But note that with the correct rights logfiles can be changed. The last change date of files can also be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cat .bash_history` to see what commands have been entered.

You should also check the various /var/log files. Note that you can use `tail -f` to watch the logs in real time to see if someones on the box.

Answer (score 0):

`last -w` will tell you who logged in and from where. It can be changed, like the other things. You can write a script to run as a daemon that sends the log and history files to another server, so next time it's undeletable.

I found this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script

If you setup the script to run at an interval (using sleep and a loop or some other method) and run the script from the destination server, it can't be turned off, although after the password to the owner of the files is changed, it won't be able to transfer it anymore, but by then it'll be too late.